# Azure DevOps access the files generated using the pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying the REST APIs available in [Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). The intention of it is to trigger the test cases (angular application) programmatically. I've defined the pipeline and able to successfully invoke it using the [Run API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).
In the pipeline definition yaml file, we have the below task

```
  - task: PublishTestResults@3
    displayName: 'Publish unit testing results'
    inputs:
      searchFolder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/unit-test-reports
      testRunTitle: myngapp ui
      testResultsFormat: JUnit
      testResultsFiles: '**/TESTS*.xml'
```

This checks the TESTS*.xml file to create a report.

I wanted to access these files via the API. Is it possible for me to access these files via the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first archive the files and then publish the build artifact.

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
  
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

After that, you should be able to use this REST API to get the files:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1

Comment: Thanks Bowman. i too had thought about publishing the artifacts approach, and later querying the artifacts via the API.
Are there any other options other than this? Where we can access the files that are generated during the build without publishing the artifacts?

Comment: You can't, unless your build pushes it somewhere.

Comment: @Apps No, you can't.